# Questions regarding scala syntax in the following dynamic programming solution taken from leetcode

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

Code snippet taken from [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/perfect-squares/discuss/288719/Scala-functional-and-recursive-solution-using-memoization):

```
object Solution {
    def numSquares(n: Int): Int = {
    def memoize[I, O](f: I => O): I => O = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[I, O]() {
      override def apply(key: I): O = getOrElseUpdate(key, f(key))
    }

    lazy val numSq: Int => Int = memoize {
      case 0 => 0
      case x => Range(math.sqrt(x).toInt, 1, -1).foldLeft(x)((a , b) => math.min(numSq(x - b * b) + 1, a))    
    }
    numSq(n)
  }
}
```

Since `numSq` is using mutable HashMap, Is it correct to say that `numSq` is mutable function?

Normally, when using top-down approach in dp, it usually causes stack-overflow on large inputs - but here it seems to work fine even for some larger inputs. Is it because of using `lazy val` in `numSq` definition?

Comment: a "mutable function" doesn't totally make sense. Usually you'd talk about pure and impure functions. That usually only matters if the mutability is somehow leaked to the caller of a function. The only side effect leaked to the caller in this case is memory usage and stack safety. Usually you don't call a function impure because of those things. The implementation is impure, but from the callers perspective that doesn't matter.

Comment: Right! It's the data which can be mutable or immutable but functions are described as pure/impure. I should have said pure/impure. Thank you.

Comment: I got the memory usage part in context with impurity but not sure stack safety. What it means to be stack safe? Does it mean that 'stack-safe' function wont cause stack-overflow? Also, is this implementation is stack safe?

Answer (score 1):

> ... is it correct to say that `numSq` is mutable function?

As @gregghz has noted in the comments, "mutable function" isn't a common terminology. It's true that the `HashMap` is in a different state with each recursive call, but that is effectively invisible to the caller.

> ... it seems to work fine even for some larger inputs. Is it because of using `lazy val` in `numSq` definition?

No.

The variable `numSq` is declared `lazy` in order to allow the resulting function to be recursive. Without the `lazy` part the compiler complains about an illegal forward reference.

```
Error: forward reference extends over definition of value numSq
```

`numSq` can handle large input numbers because the memoization (the memory of what has already been calculated) reduces the number of recursions required to calculate the next result.

Notice that you can get a StackOverflow simply by reversing the `Range` direction:

```
Range(2, math.sqrt(x).toInt + 1)...
```

By starting with the small numbers and incrementing, the `HashMap` won't contain enough elements to sufficiently reduce the recursion required as the numbers grow.

Comment: Changing `lazy val` to `def` passes the compilation but it gets quite slow. Leetcode reports 1150ms runtime on `lazy val` version but with the `def` version the code works for small inputs but on final submission, leetcode says it is out of memory on some test case! I was wondering if `def` is using/causing more stack-frames whereas `lazy val` is resulting in lower number of stack-frames. Or perhaps, the only reason of this performance difference is that `def` is evaluated every time unlike `lazy val`. Or is there any other reason for this performance difference?

Comment: On analyzing further, it appears that `def` is resulting in no memoization because a new HashMap gets created on each invocation of `numSq`. Is this correct? Is there any other reason for performance difference apart from this?

Comment: Yes, a `def` is re-evaluated with every invocation so, as a method instead of a function, `numSq()` would re-create an empty `HashMap` with every recursion, thus no memoization.